# mysql group by without changing the order of the list in union all

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

This is my query

```
select id from ((select id from users where id = 2 
)
union all 
(select id from users where id = 1 
)
union all 
(select id from users where id = 1 
)
union all 
(select id from users where id = 4 
)
union all 
(select id from users where id = 3 
)
)results group by id
```

The output I got was

```
id
----
1
2
3
4
```

The output I expected was

```
id
----
2
1
4
3
```

Is there any solution for it?

I need the result group by id but not an ordered list.

Comment: may we know specific reason to use union all ??

Comment: This is not the exact query. Each union all query is taking values from different tables and for selecting id. The purpose is to select in correct order

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you need  something like this Not union all

```
SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4);
```